# Change navigationItem leftBarButtonItem depending on segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

I'm going through an Apple tutorial where a simple task-tracking app is created. There is a dynamic table view with a list of tasks and a static table view that serves both for adding a new task (in this case it's presented modally after user taps "+" button in navigationItem) and for editing existing task (in this case it is pushed via navigation controller after user selects one of the cells in dynamic table view).

The tutorial says that static table view should have a "Cancel" leftBarButtonItem set in IB. To me, a "Cancel" button is ok when a new task is being created, but when an existing task is being viewed or edited, a standard navigation "Back" button with an arrow would be more appropriate. Tutorial completely ignores this UI issue, and I can't seem to find a way to switch between two button types depending on which segue is being performed. The only thing that comes to mind is creating to separate table views, but that looks like a waste of time and resource for the sake of a single button. Maybe there's a simpler and more obvious way?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, sometimes only after asking a question you find an obvious answer. This line of code:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = navigationItem.backBarButtonItem
```

, added either in prepareForSegue() of dynamic table view or in viewDidLoad() of the static table view resolves the issue and substitutes the "Cancel" button set in IB for modal presentation to system-standard navigation back button.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let backButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.bacButAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Your Image"), for: .normal)
    backButton.sizeToFit()
    let leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
    leftBarButtonItem.title = "Your Title"

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem



func bacButAction()
{
 //do action here
}
```